# is there a simple way to draw coordinates for SKnodes obstacles from images?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, ios-universal-app

I am creating a game and I need to draw some obstacles on in (SKNodes), depending on the level (background image).
Let's say I have a tree, i would like to draw borders around it as in the picture below:

[image]

I will need the coordinates to create a physicsBody.

Is there a simple way to do it? (maybe a software?)

I will need to adapt the same coordinates for different devices, therefore I believe it's too complicated to manually do it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You want the coordinates to actually draw the border or to create a physicsBody?

Comment: yes! exactly what i wanted to say :-) @ZeMoon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a SKPhysicsBody class method that could be of help:

[`+ bodyWithTexture:size:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithTexture:size:)

From the description:

> Use this method when your sprite has a shape that you want replicated
>   in its physics body. The texture is scaled to the new size and then
>   analyzed. A new physics body is created that includes all of the
>   texels in the texture that have a nonzero alpha value. The shape of
>   this body attempts to strike a good balance between performance and
>   accuracy. For example, fine details may be ignored if keeping them
>   would cause a significant performance penalty.

Comment: So this could potentially work with png transparent images. It's quite interesting. Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [SKPhysicsBody Path Generator](http://insyncapp.net/SKPhysicsBodyPathGenerator.html).

You can easily create a path as you desire with this tool (but make sure you read the rules at the top right)